# Is there any RPM online factory for Fedora?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I want some online service that will allow me:

- Build RPM from my provided sources and spec-files;
- Create and edit spec-files online, using some predefined templates (CMake, autotools, etc.);
- Provide some suggestions and make some automation (like, auto-collect installed files, etc.);
- Let me choose the stable, beta, or rawhide Fedora environment to build with.

I've heard, that such services exist for Ubuntu and OpenSuSE.
Does anything like this exist for Fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there isn't any service that exists like this. Your best bet would be to use the Fedora build system tools [Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock), and [Koji](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji), then try to integrate the other functionality you're looking for. It might also be worth taking a look at [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm).